# how to checked only one checkbox in ng-repeat checkbox using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

when i go to page i need always checked somecheck boxes like software or harware.if any one selected then only submit button will visible.if nothing is selected submit button should disable and alert should come please select some services

```js
function Test1Controller($scope) {
  var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
  var serverData = ["software", "hardware", "Accessories"];
  $scope.items = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
    var modal = {
      name: serverData[i],
      selected: i === 0 ? true : false,

    };
    $scope.items.push(modal);
  }

  $scope.check = function() {
    var checkedItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
        checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
      }
    }
    console.log(checkedItems);
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Test1Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" />{{item.name}}
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `selected: false` in `for` to `selected: i === 0 ? true : false,` to set first checkbox checked by default

Comment: how can i validate here everytime only one checkbox is selected then only submit but will submit visible

Comment: If they can only select one option, you should consider using radiobuttons instead of checkboxes. Checkboxes are when you have multiple options and you can select multiple 'answers'. Give your radiobuttons the same name and they will be able to choose just one radiobutton. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Test1Controller($scope) {
  var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
  var serverData = ["software", "hardware", "Accessories"];
  $scope.items = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
    var selectVal = false;
    if(serverData[i] === "hardware"){
        selectVal = true;
    }
    var modal = {
      name: serverData[i],
      selected: selectVal

    };
    $scope.items.push(modal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been struggling to resolve this issue for 2 days